# new ArrayList<T> (T[] arr)

Tags: java

Okay So this doesnt make sense to me.... maybe someone can shed some light.
A technique I figure out for converting primitive arrays into ArrayLists is as follows.

```
arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(primitveArray));
```

this works quit well. 
But today, I start wondering how efficent this was, since I happened to be writing some code where performance is more important then It had been in other applications I had worked on in the past and decided to look at the source code for `Arrays.asList()`

I found this:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... array) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(array);
}
```

And I said to myself: "Im such an idiot, Its just passing the array into the ArrayList constructor `ArrayList<T>(T[] arr)`, why dont I just skip a step and not use the stupid Arrays.asList?

So i try this

```
arr = new ArrayList<T>(primitveArray)
```

in my code. But then suddenly `ArrayList<T>(T[] arr)` is undefined. Im quite confused why this would be?

Comment: If you look into the API you'll notice that there's no *public* ArrayList constructor that takes an array.

Comment: Note that `String` isn't a primitive. `Arrays.asList` won't work for actual primitive arrays - for example `Arrays.asList(new int[3])` will give you a single element `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But then suddenly `ArrayList<T>(T[] arr)` is undefined. I'm quite confused why this would be?

There are two classes named `ArrayList`:

- one is a `private` `static` inner class of `java.util.Arrays`;
- the other is `java.util.ArrayList`.

`asList()` uses the former. You are trying to use the latter. The two classes are unrelated, they just happen to share the same name.

It is important to note that `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` does not copy the array. It provides a view onto it.

Answer (score 2):

> So i try this `arr = new ArrayList<T>(primitveArray)`

`T` is a generically typed parameter, you cannot use it when instanciating an ArrayList, only when declaring its use in a Class or method. Instead, change your code to:

`arr = Arrays.asList(primitveArray);`

The ArrayList class used in the Arrays class is different from the ArrayList class you use in your code, it is an inner class defined in the Arrays class itself, and defines a constructor taking an Array as an argument. Since this class is private, with a non-public constructor, it can only be instanciated and used within the `Arrays` class itself.

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements RandomAccess, java.io.Serializable
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2764017481108945198L;
    private final E[] a;

    ArrayList(E[] array) {
            if (array==null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
        a = array;
    }

...
```

Comment: I dont this it is this. 'arr = Arrays.asList(primitveArray)' doenst work since it is reducing type down from ArrayList to List which is unsafe.  And also if you read my question I pointed out that Arrays uses the 'ArrayList<T>(T[] arr);' constructor as if it were public. You cant access private method in other classes just becuase they are in the same package. Private works at the class level. Like I point out in my own answer, Arrays implements its own local ArrayList.

Comment: @gbtimmon while both classes are named ArrayList they are different, java.util.ArrayList which is public does not have the right ctor, java.util.Arrays.ArrayList which is private does have the ctor but is not related to the other ArrayList.

Comment: @gbtimmon there's a difference between `package private` (which is the default in java) and `private`. You can access package private methods of classes in the same package. If the `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` constructor used by asList is package private.

Comment: There's some more stuff happening here, as even private methods of inner classes can be called from outer classes. So the constructor being package private doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Interestingly enough, In my source code for java.utilArrayList, (Java 6 EE) there is no private 'ArrayList<T>(T[] arr);' constructor, there is no 'ArrayList<T>(T[] arr);' at all.

Comment: @gbtimmon there's package private constructor in java.util.Arrays.ArrayList ;)

Comment: And there shouldn't be, which is the point others are trying to make. The ArrayList you use in your source code and the ArrayList used inside the Arrays class are not the same type. The one used inside Arrays is its own implementation of an AbstractList. It just so happens that it is also named ArrayList.

Comment: Okay I get what your saying. Thats obvious, I thought you were saying the constructor was in java.util.ArrayList, which didnt make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so about ten secounds after asking this questions I figured it out. Apprently `java.util.Arrays` implements a static local class called ArrayList which is seperate than `java.util.ArrayList`. Confusingly enough they are both named ArrayList, but where as `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` is declared as

```
private static class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements
        List<E>, Serializable, RandomAccess
```

`java.util.ArrayList` is declared as

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>,
    Cloneable, Serializable, RandomAccess
```

I guess the question reamins now, why the would do this. Probably optimization I suppose. Since Array is casting the ArrayList to a List it only need to support just enough to perform the List operation without the rest of the `ArrayList`s normal functionality.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the question reamins now, why the would do this

The returned list is a view of the array, no copy takes place and any change to the list is visible in the source array. Since it is allways backed by the source array any modifications affecting the lists size are unsupported and throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing for you to realize is that `Arrays.asList` is **utterly performant**, it's O(1) with a **very small** fixed overhead. This is because no data is being copied. It just gives your array a `List` interface to interact with it. Second, the `private static class ArrayList` is indeed very important since the `public class ArrayList` **does copy** the data and results in performance degradation.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess the question reamins now, why the would do this.

The `List` returned by `Arrays.asList` (an `Arrays.ArrayList`). Is a view of the original array. If you change it, the array changes, if you change the array, it changes. If you try to do anything that resizes it, it throws an exception, because you can't resize primitive arrays.

It's just an adapter to efficiently treat the primitive array as a `List` without having to copy the elements into a new implementation of `List`.

When you do

```
new java.util.ArrayList( Arrays.asList( primitiveArray ) );
```

is when you are copying the elements. The result is not a view, but is independent of the original array. And also, you gained the ability to resize it. If you look at the source code (you have to look at both `java.util.ArrayList` and `Arrays.ArrayList`, you can see that it's copying those elements in the most efficient way possible, from the original primitive array into the array that is backing the `java.util.ArrayList`, so there is no loss of efficiency to worry about.

Comment: Actually there is, but its not where I thought it was. We dont ever resize the ArrayLists that we are passing back, so I assume if I return List instead of ArrayList and just have return Arrays.asList() Im going to save some cycles.